# Self hosted tool for managing updates to an iOS Enterprise app

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

I'm searching for a solution to a) distribute and b) update an enterprise iOS app to our users. I'm searching for something like HockeyKit, but not that outdated.
We'd like to host it by ourself, so an open source solution would be ideal. I know solutions like hockey app and testflight, but we'd prefer a solution that is free and does not require any review by apple ;)

Android support is not a prerequisite, but would be a nice bonus.

Can anybody recommend a good solution?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we used hockey app instead.

Comment: Have you tried Xcode Server?